# mysql create table command add ons question

Tags: mysql, database

My team has added these statements with the create tables after the columns are defined:

ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC AUTO_INCREMENT=465

The question is the table is a country lookup table. so we know it has a fixed list values of about 275-ish. And this table will be 99% a read only table. Very rare will be any write if i need to update any colunm property.

So do i need all that stuff beyond 'ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'? this is just one table, they have these for all most all tables and i cant understand why lookup tables will have all these commands/

Comment: Are you sure that these were manually added ? I work with Oracle and Toad and frequenly extract the ddl for database objects. Even though you create the table using the bare minimum syntax, when you extract the DDL (using a tool/ API ), it adds on all the additional options that were not given when creating the original table, but were defaulted based on your database settings.

Comment: It is part of the phpMyAdmin SQL Dump. so i guess someone added it, either the team or the tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can look up all those in [the CREATE TABLE doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).

You're right though. For the context you describe, they're almost surely completely unnecessary.

**Asides**

Re: `AUTO_INCREMENT` as part of your `CREATE TABLE` -- yeah, that's just because it was part of the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` of a *live* table, not because it was part of your teams intentions/ongoing script.  No biggie.

Note that `CHECKSUM` and `DELAY_KEY_WRITE` are for MyISAM tables only. If that table was InnoDB, the *features* those two parameters bring are arguably implicitly taken care of (i.e. table integrity and write issues).

> Why do we need innoDB for read only lookup tables? I thought innoDB is better for write intensive tables?

Sorry. I didn't mean to imply that you *needed* InnoDB. It's just a reflex. :)

Wheater or not InnoDB performs better for writing depends on the usage pattern / application. For your context, I wouldn't expect you seeing a performance difference weither you use MyISAM or InnoDB. At any rate, as a rule of thumb, since InnoDB can be acid complient, more resistant to corruption, and stored in memory (in InnoDB's buffer pool) I always advocate for it. MyISAM fails on all those counts.

Comment: It is part of the phpMyAdmin SQL Dump. but why do we need innoDB for read only lookup tables? I thought innoDB is better for write intensive tables? As for auto increment i am not sure. it has value of 465 but the table anyways wont have more than 275 items as there are not that many countries in the world, so i am not sure.